MySQL version 8.0, select count(*) from largish table (40 million rows) takes ~220 seconds
MySQL version 8.0, select count(*) from largish table (40 million rows) takes ~220 seconds.
There are no large object columns, just varchar and int and there are only 25 columns.  I can use Information_Schema to get a row count but it is an approximation and I need a precise number.
EXPLAIN says the count is doing an index range scan on a non-unique index, I tried to force it to use the unique primary index but this was slower.
Seems to be much quicker on version 5.7
